# UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrg() in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there a way in an LWC javascript file to determine easily whether an org is **multi-currency**?  Or do we need to do a remote (apex) call to get this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no such Utility as discussed in the document [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_salesforce_modules).

You can write a bit of apex to achieve this easily

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getIsMultiCurrencyOrg from '@salesforce/apex/UserUtility.getIsMultiCurrencyOrg';


export default class IsMultiCurrencyOrg extends LightningElement {
  @wire(getIsMultiCurrencyOrg, {})
  isMultiCurrencyOrg;
}
```

A template to test this is as below

```
<template>
   {isMultiCurrencyOrg.data}
</template>
```

If you need this as a Utility i recommend you create a service component as shown in the blog [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/lightning-web-components-service-components.html).

Also read this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_share_code) for sharing Javascript.

Comment: You can call a method in Apex from any component, no need to complicate this with a separate component (unless you've got other stuff in there, too).

Comment: @sfdcfox I agree but at same time i am not sure of total context of the app. If multiple components require it then it is good idea to wrap this in a service component and then just import them as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Lightning Locker blocks access to global Javascript object that we use in the past like: **Aura**, **sfdc** or **sForce**.

So we do not have a way to solve it without using apex, a cacheable method (since that value will not change much) that returns any of these booleans is what you need:

`Boolean multiCurrencyEnabled = Schema.getGlobalDescribe (). ContainsKey ('CurrencyType');`

`Boolean multiCurrencyEnabled = UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization ();`

I also hope in the future that they expose us an object to solve those kinds of things

Comment: You can save the global describe and just do `return Type.forName('Schema.CurrencyType') != null;` (or, of course, the UserInfo method would be ideal).

Comment: I total Agree, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys.